# Mount Azure File Share on local Kubernetes (Docker Desktop Mac)

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

Did anyone manage to mount an **Azure File Share** on Kubernetes in **Docker Desktop for Mac**.

I get the following error:

```
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t cifs -o dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,gid=1000,mfsymlinks,nobrl,uid=1000,vers=3.0,<masked> //datapylotstorage.file.core.windows.net/dp-share-workflow-test-dev-example-share /var/lib/kubelet/pods/c31c6fce-f573-430e-8a58-16ebf29e0c5e/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/dp-share-workflow-test-dev-example-share
Output: mount: /var/lib/kubelet/pods/c31c6fce-f573-430e-8a58-16ebf29e0c5e/volumes/kubernetes.io~azure-file/dp-share-workflow-test-dev-example-share: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program.
```

I can connect by Python SDK to the File Share from within a container in Kubernetes. Do I have to configure my mac, so that kubernetes can mount the volume?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if the problem like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525243/why-do-i-get-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error) one, you can try to install the package `nfs-common` in the MacOS.